# Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run test cases on my local server through Jenkins, Firstly everything works fine but from some time I am facing error of `Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`.
After doing some googling i found to set display variable

```
key : DISPLAY

value:0:0
```

On your server start Xvfb in the background:

```
Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

But on starting Xvfb I am getting another error

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
```

I am using `chrome version 48` and `chrome driver 2.20` in `linux 14.04 LTS`

so now what should be done ?

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the lock 
`rm -f /tmp/.X1-lock`

And then grep the running processes:
`ps -ef | grep X`
`kill -0 <PID>`

Then try `Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &` again

Now you may run `google-chrome &`